# Rails rspec shoulda matcher validating uniqueness of case insensitive item failing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I'm trying to be a good rails developer and write tests as I go.  I've run into something I'm unclear on and am looking for advice.  I have a model that has a unique case insensitive attribute.  The test is failing however.  Whats the correct way to test this?  What am I doing wrong?

```
class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end

RSpec.describe Tenant, type: :model do
  it { should validate_presence_of :name }
  it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:name).case_insensitive }
end
```

It seems like it's trying to set the id as `nil` even though we have another validation that requires the presence.  But why is it doing that while testing name?  I'm confused.

Test shows the following result;

```
Failures:

 1) Tenant Validates Uniqueness of should validate that :name is case-insensitively unique
 Failure/Error: self.id = self.id.downcase

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/models/tenant.rb:17:in `block in <class:Tenant>'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validator.rb:96:in `perform_validation'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validator.rb:89:in `validation_result'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validator.rb:85:in `validation_error_messages'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validator.rb:64:in `messages'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validator.rb:25:in `has_messages?'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validator.rb:55:in `messages_match?'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validator.rb:21:in `call'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher/attribute_setters_and_validators.rb:38:in `matches?'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher/attribute_setters_and_validators.rb:24:in `each'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher/attribute_setters_and_validators.rb:24:in `detect'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher/attribute_setters_and_validators.rb:24:in `first_passing'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb:533:in `public_send'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb:533:in `run'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/allow_value_matcher.rb:400:in `does_not_match?'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/disallow_value_matcher.rb:32:in `matches?'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validation_matcher.rb:155:in `run_allow_or_disallow_matcher'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_model/validation_matcher.rb:93:in `disallows_value_of'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/validate_uniqueness_of_matcher.rb:606:in `validate_two_records_with_same_non_blank_value_cannot_coexist?'
 # /Users/a/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/shoulda-matchers-3.1.2/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/validate_uniqueness_of_matcher.rb:330:in `matches?'
 # ./spec/models/tenant_spec.rb:49:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

 Finished in 0.09495 seconds (files took 1.89 seconds to load)
 2 examples, 1 failure

 Failed examples:

 rspec ./spec/models/tenant_spec.rb:49 # Tenant Validates Uniqueness of should validate that :name is case-insensitively unique
```

Note: this is likely something dumb and obvious that I'm just missing.  Your help/advice is appreciated.

Versions:
Ruby 2.50 :: Rails 5.14 :: Rspec 3.7 :: Shoulda-matcher 3.12

Comment: It seems you have some before/after hooks defined. Please show more code of `Tenant` model class.

Comment: Yep that was it.  The module I pulled my example out of had some before validation hooks deep inside that I had to go dig out.. thank you!

Comment: but how do you solved it? just removing the hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [nattfodd mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49237245/rails-rspec-shoulda-matcher-validating-uniqueness-of-case-insensitive-item-faili/49240610#comment85479452_49237245):

> It seems you have some before/after hooks defined. Please show more code of `Tenant` model class.

It was a beforehook that was the issue.